# How to type a function that partially applies another function?

Tags: typescript

This is the javascript function I want to provide a JsDoc with type signature for:

```
function provideExtra(f, extra) {
  return (props, ...args) => f({ ...props, extra }, ...args)
}
```

I think it should be something like this, but I can't get it right:

```
/**
 * @param {(props: Props, ...args: Args) => Result} f
 * @param {Extra} extra
 * @template Extra
 * @template {{ extra: Extra }} Props
 * @template {Array} Args
 * @template Result
 * @returns {(props: Omit<Props, 'extra'>, ...args: Args) => Result}
 */
```

I have `Omit` defined as `type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>`

If this can not be done in a JsDoc, but can be done in a `.d.ts` file that is fine too.

---

*update*

A version that works from the outside:

```
/**
 * @template {Object} P
 * @template {Array} A
 * @template R
 * @param {(props: P, ...args: A) => R} f
 * @param {P['extra']} extra
 * @returns {(props: Omit<P, 'extra'>, ...args: A) => R}
 */
export function provideExtra(f, extra) {
  return (props, ...args) => f(Object.assign({}, props, { extra }), ...args)
}
```

This however produces an error for `Object.assign`:

> Argument of type `Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "extra">> & { extra: P["extra"]; }` is not assignable to parameter of type 'P'. [2345]

In my naive mind it that type would result in `P`; leaving out `extra` and intersecting it with something that has `extra` with the correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
function provideExtra<Props,Extra,Args extends any[],Result>(
  f: (p: Props & {extra: Extra}, ...args: Args) => Result,
  extra: Extra
) {
  return (props: Props, ...args: Args) => f({ ...props, extra }, ...args)
}
```

UPD. Yes, you're right: TypeScript doesn't infer `Props` as expected. You'd have to call it like this:

```
const f = (props: {prefix: string, extra: string}, suffix: string) => props.prefix + props.extra + suffix;
const g = provideExtra<{prefix: string},string,[string],string>(f,"mid");
```

With some type inferrence I was able to reduce the number of type arguments:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type FirstArg<F> = F extends (p: infer U, ...args: any[]) => any ? U : never;
type Extra<F> = FirstArg<F> extends {extra: infer U} ? U : never;
type OtherProps<F> = Omit<FirstArg<F>,"extra" & keyof FirstArg<F>> & { extra?: never};
type Rest<F> = F extends (p: any, ...args: infer V) => any ? V : never;

function provideExtra<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  f: (p: OtherProps<F> & {extra: Extra<F>}, ...args: Rest<F>) => ReturnType<F>,
  extra: Extra<F>
) {
  return (props: OtherProps<F>, ...args: Rest<F>) => f({ ...props, extra }, ...args)
}

const f = (props: {prefix: string, extra: string}, suffix: string) => props.prefix + props.extra + suffix;
const g = provideExtra<typeof f>(f,"mid");
const t = g({prefix: "prefix"}, "suffix");
```

But unless there is a simpler solution, I'd probably just add a type assertion, as `Omit<P, "extra"> & { extra: P["extra"]; }` is clearly a `P`.

Comment: Now the resulting function requires the same props as `f`, it should not require the `extra` prop.

Comment: Yes, sorry. `Props` are not inferred as well as one would hope. I updated the answer.